# How can I wrap parameter value in URL to include parameter separator

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am working on project in alfresco, and need to send a value as a keyword to do the search.
Now, my question is, can I wrap that value somehow to include **&** separator also?
My URL looks like:

https://myproject/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/search?term=belux&50&qw

The value that I am sending as a parameter is:
**belux&50&qw**

The problem is when I done the search, search engine get confused and read that parameter as **belux** only. Probably search engine looks on that & as on separator an as soon as he finds it he stops, that is, reads the value to the first character only.
In my case, he reads only **belux**.

Is it posible to read the whole value, including the & sight?

Thanks,

Comment: you need to use `urlencode` to escape the `&` so that it becomes `belux%2650%26qw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**URLEncoder** is the solution. You just need to remember to encode only the name and/or value of the individual query string parameter, not the whole URL, and certainly not the query string parameter separator character & or the parameter name-value separator character =.
Example :

```
String url = "https://example.com?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("belux&50&qw", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```